# Zero EJB and class not found after migrate glassfish 2.1 to 4.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I have trouble migrating an EJB with SOAP webservices and included JARS from Glassfish 2.1 to Glassfish 4.0. At the same time I changed my OS (XP->Windows 7) and netbeans version 7.3 to 7.4. The Glassfish 4.0 is a cluster with 2 instances.

I created new packages with the use of the sources. The used jars are included as libraries (like in GF 2.0). The EJB builds fine, but when I deploy I get these errors.

```
[2014-05-07T11:05:36.974+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=208 _ThreadName=admin-listener(13)] [timeMillis: 1399453536974] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Class [ nl/amnesty/sys/webform/entity/Form ] not found. Error while loading [ class nl.amnesty.webservice.form.FormExternal ]]]
[2014-05-07T11:05:36.975+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=208 _ThreadName=admin-listener(13)] [timeMillis: 1399453536975] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while deploying the app [CRMWebserviceForm]]]
[2014-05-07T11:05:36.976+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=208 _ThreadName=admin-listener(13)] [timeMillis: 1399453536976] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ejb jar CRMWebserviceForm: it contains zero ejb. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session/entity/message driven bean.
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:112)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:621)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.visit(EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.java:757)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ApplicationValidator.accept(ApplicationValidator.java:116)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:621)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:190)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:878)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:818)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:374)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
]]

[2014-05-07T11:05:36.979+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=208 _ThreadName=admin-listener(13)] [timeMillis: 1399453536979] [levelValue: 1000] [[

 Exception while deploying the app [CRMWebserviceForm] : Invalid ejb jar CRMWebserviceForm: it contains zero ejb. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session/entity/message driven bean.]]
```

A part of the EJB:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;



@WebService
@Stateless
public class FormExternal {


    @WebMethod(operationName = "submitform")
    public long submitform(@WebParam(name = "form") Form form) {

    CRMWebformController.processForm(form);
    return form.getSubmissionid();
    }
}
```

Here some information on how the jar libraries are included.

```
- CRMWebserviceForm
  + Source packages
  + Test packages
    - Libraries
      - NLAmestyCRM - dist/NLAmnestyCRM.jar
      - ...
      - NLAmnestyWEBFORM - dist/NLAmnestyWEBFORM.jar
      + JDK 1.7 (default)
      + Cluster (glassfish)
```

In the EJB properties (libraries) they are selected to be required at runtime. The libraries folder I added later and by "mistake". It is .\lib\nblibraries.properties and did not make any difference. To be more precise I added that value at EJB properties "Library folder" by hitting "browse" but did not add anything to that folder.

The packaging-option "Package required JARS in EJB jar" is selected.

Run: Java EE version is Java EE5. Is that compatible with platform JDK 1.7?

Any help is appreciated.

[Edit: some code added]
[Edit: library information added]

Comment: Please add some example code of your EJBs. You are probably using some old EJB 2.x stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The problems are related. Because the class `nl.amnesty.sys.webform.entity.Form` can't be found, the EJB(s) which use(s) this class can't be loaded, therefore you get the message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ejb jar CRMWebserviceForm: it contains
 zero ejb. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session/entity/message driven bean.
```

You have to make sure that the class is packaged with your web application or available in the `lib` folder of your GlassFish installation so that it can be loaded by the server.

I don't know how you are packaging you application but if you can't get it to work, maybe some information about that is helpful.

Comment: how do you make it available in the lib folder?